# Bad File descriptor error in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode

I opened my xcode project today and pulled the latest version of the source. To my surprise, I recieved an error stating "(Xcode) encoutered read error on command output pipe (Bad file descriptor)"

I am totally confused by this error and I have no idea what caused it. Could anyone shed some light on why I might be seeing this error and a possible fix? I am running xcode v9

I looked on google and there didn't seem to be much on the issue. Still looking though.

Comment: "I opened my xcode project today and pulled the latest version of the source." Try to go back to an older version? Then check the modifications done?

Comment: Yes, I created a branch with the previous commit. Luckly though, the mods are not too extensive and I was able to add them back into the source files. The error went away. I made some minor changes and when I merged the branch into the master, the error also went away. Unfortunately, I do not have syntax highlighting or intellisense (or whatever Apple calls it) in the master. But I have it in the branch

Comment: What could goes wrong is a wrong xib/storyboard usually or the .pbxproj that during a merge failed (happens).

Comment: AH I see, I copied the entire file from my branch view controller to the master view controller and that seemed to fix things for now